# Jasmine inject function fails when using fat arrow functions

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm just starting to unit test my app, and have successfully gotten one test suite to run, yeah!  I moved on to start testing a second controller, and as soon as the test runner (karma) hits an `inject` block, the test fails.  Comment it out, and the tests pass again.  Can't for the life of me figure out what might be going on.  Very basic karma config:

https://gist.github.com/ggoforth/82510af339370a4dca32ad4c0c4b0563

The controller looks like:

```
angular.module('somemodule')
  .controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl);

function SomeCtrl($rootScope, Notification) {
  $rootScope.$on('someapp.apiLimitExceeded', (evt, err) => {
    Notification.error({
      message: err.data.message
    });
  });
}
```

The first test looks like:

```
describe('SomeCtrl', () => {
  let $rootScope, controller, notification;

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('mymodule');

    inject(($injector) => {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      notification = $injector.get('Notification');

      spyOn(notification, 'error');

      controller = $injector.get('$controller')('SomeCtrl', {
        $rootScope: $rootScope,
        Notification: notification 
      });
    });
  });

  describe('Initialization', () => {
    it('Should register a $rootScope listener for mymodule.apiLimitExceeded', () => {
      const args = {data: {message: 'dis an errr'}};
      $rootScope.$emit('mymodule.apiLimitExceeded', args);

      expect(notification.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(notification.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args.data);
      expect(notification.error.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    });
  });
});
```

This test passes, as expected.  If I literally copy and paste the contents of this file into another test file, without changing anything, the tests start failing.  Removing the second test file makes the original test start passing.  I must be missing something about how karma is running these angular tests, or some tearDown I'm not performing, but I can't see what that might be.  Any ideas?  The error I get, for reference is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at Function.fb.$$annotate (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/build/js/deps.js:7451:410)
at Function.angular.injector.$$annotate (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2615:36)
at e (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/build/js/deps.js:7298:368)
at Object.invoke (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/build/js/deps.js:7299:86)
at Object.workFn (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2965:20)
at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2934:42)
at Object.beforeEach (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/test/test.again.someapp.controller.js:7:5)
Error: Declaration Location
at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2927:25)
at Object.beforeEach (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/test/test.again.someapp.controller.js:7:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined
at Object.it (/Users/greg/projects/someapp/client/test/test.again.someapp.controller.js:23:17)
```

**UPDATE**

The issue was that I was using untranspiled ES6, which included using fat arrow functions for my inject blocks.  Apparently there is an issue with Chrome 50/51 where you MUST use a normal function.  Changing the fat arrow version to normal function fixes the issue (or transpile your test files via a babel preprocessor).

Comment: The question doesn't contain the details that could help to trace the problem. Recreating the problem in Plunker would help, if possible. There are too many possibilities why it can be like that, e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12424

Comment: I'm not sure how a Plunker would help.  This is an issue when I run unit tests with karma.  Using the exact config and test files above, a single unit test runs fine.  If I copy and paste the exact same test the tests fail with the stated error.

Comment: There are too many moving parts to blame it on Karma alone. Have you tried to run the specs *without* Karma? The said Chrome and Angular versions may cause problems, and there's no information on which package versions are used.

Comment: @estus I figured the issue out, and it was an issue with ngMock, specifcally the `inject` method.  As seen above, I was using fat arrow functions for my inject function.  Apparently there is a bug in Chrome 50/51 with these, so replacing the fat arrow function with a normal anon function fixes the issue...Thanks for taking the time to respond, you were right, wasn't anything to do with Karma.  Found this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14487

Comment: As a quick update, I've added the babel preprocessor to process my test files and that allows me to use all the ES6 goodness in my tests.  I'm gonna update the post title to reflect the findings here and hopefully help anyone else that is pulling their hair out over this.  Thanks again @estus!